# `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` according to Chrome's console

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, syntax-error

[image]

How is this closing bracket *unexpected*?

```
function pollCreateOptions_addOption ()
{ // Opening of curly bracket 1
    var highestN = 0;

    $('table#options tr td fieldset').each
    ( // Opening of normal bracket 1
        function (i, option)
        { // Opening of curly bracket 2
            alert (this.attr ('name'));
        { // Closing of curly bracket 2
    ); // Closing of normal bracket 1
} // Closing of curly bracket 1
```

Comment: Might want to check your eyeglass prescription :-)

Comment: @Pointy Do you think these goggles would be enough? http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/98a392c9a0a6d6f15dc815d8c8dd8778?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG Maybe I should consider having a telescope mounted on my head when scripting :p

Comment: Upvoted your question because I've been there before and I am sure this is not my last time of having been there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('table#options tr td fieldset').each
    ( 
        function (i, option)
        { 
            alert (this.attr ('name'));

        } // not {
    );
```

Comment: Noes seriously? >.< Half an hour of searching and this was the problem? -.-

Comment: @RobinJ sometime it happens, no fact buddy, carry on

Answer (score 1):

you should use closing `}` instead of openning `{` here : `{ // Closing of curly bracket 2`

```
function pollCreateOptions_addOption ()
{ // Opening of curly bracket 1
    var highestN = 0;

    $('table#options tr td fieldset').each
    ( // Opening of normal bracket 1
        function (i, option)
        { // Opening of curly bracket 2
            alert (this.attr ('name'));
        } // Closing of curly bracket 2
    ); // Closing of normal bracket 1
} // Closing of curly bracket 1
```